# How to find url through regex in python?

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

How can I find all the URL having the regex pattern.

I am trying to find all the url having a pattern through regex but it gives in error TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

I am using python 3.5.1

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import re
 r = urllib.request.urlopen('http://i.cantonfair.org.cn/en/expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=404').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r,"html.parser")

regex = '(<a href="expexhibitorlist.aspx\?categoryno=)?[0-9]+?>'
pattern = re.compile(regex)
mycateurl = re.findall(pattern,soup)
print (mycateurl)
```

Comment: Wow, do people still [parse html with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5827958)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You the [`soup.find_all()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) and pass a [compiled regular expression](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression) as an `href` argument value.

Working example:

```
import re
import urllib.request

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


r = urllib.request.urlopen('http://i.cantonfair.org.cn/en/ExpExhibitorList.aspx?k=glassware')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")

links = soup.find_all("a", href=re.compile(r"expexhibitorlist\.aspx\?categoryno=[0-9]+"))
print([link["href"] for link in links])
```

Prints:

```
['expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=411', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=412', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=453', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=410', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=414', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=415', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=403', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=404', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=405', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=408', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=402', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=401', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=454', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=455', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=451', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=406', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=407', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=416', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=427', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=434', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=435', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=436', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=437', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=438', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=439', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=440', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=441', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=442', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=443', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=444', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=445', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=446', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=447', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=448', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=449', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=452', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=417', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=418', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=419', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=420', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=421', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=422', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=423', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=424', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=425', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=426', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=428', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=430', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=431', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=432', 'expexhibitorlist.aspx?categoryno=433']
```

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me what ([link["href"] for link in links]) means ?

Comment: @AmanKumar it is called a list comprehension. We are basically making a list of `href` attribute values for all links found.

Comment: Thanks. Can you send me any good link for web scraping as I am new to python and web scraping.